# Page + Custom Post Type with same category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I'm trying to display a page with related posts (FAQ) within the same category ID. Currently it displays all custom posts, but with different categories.

As an example:
 - Page has a category ID '4'.
 - Page has content
 - Under content it has a FAQ that needs to show the same category of the page (4)

My code:

```
          <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

      <div class="content">
        <div class="white-block white-bg shadow">

          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-md-9 order-md-last">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-block light-grey">


                <h1><?php the_title(); ?><br />
                  <small><?php edit_post_link(); ?></small>
                  <?php the_category(); ?>
                </h1>

                <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php
                        $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'faq', 'cat' => $cat_id, 'posts_per_page' => '3', 'post_status'=>published,) );
                          while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                       ?>

                       <a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action ">
                         <div class="col-12">
                           <div class="row">

                        <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>

                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <small><?php the_date(); ?></small>

                      </div>
                      </div>
                        <p class="mb-1">
                          <?php echo(get_the_excerpt()); ?></p>
                      </a>


                     <?php endwhile; ?>


                <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>


            <h3> FAQ </h3>


            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php
                    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'faq', 'cat' => $cat_id, 'posts_per_page' => '3', 'post_status'=>published,) );
                      while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                   ?>

                   <a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action ">
                     <div class="col-12">
                       <div class="row">

                    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>

                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <small><?php the_date(); ?></small>

                  </div>
                  </div>
                    <p class="mb-1">
                      <?php echo(get_the_excerpt()); ?></p>
                  </a>


                 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it as followed:

Within the loop I fetch the cat_ID:

```
 <?php
     foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
     $cat_id= $category->cat_ID;
   }
 ?>
```

Outside the loop I use the cat_ID:

```
'cat' => $cat_id,
```

I guess not the best solution but it works..